# Is there any way to remove background of an image fully with the help of post-processor techniques(like edge detector) after deep learning based model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm using a deep learning-based model (deep lab v3+ with xception as the backbone) for image segmentation and removing the background. The subject of the image will be a person. And my target is to extract the person from the image. But only with the machine learning model, the output is not satisfactory. I'm thinking if somehow I can detect the edge of the person with "Canny Edge detector" and use this as post processor to get exact output. I also try the blur effect for smoothing the object's edge and getting a pleasant-looking output. I saw Adobe Photoshop's "select subject" feature. It is quite accurate.
[Main image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdNQA.png) -> [segmented mask from ml-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx8UV.png) -> [adding blur effect on the edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSIps.png)

Canny Edge Detector as Post Processor:
I tried the following steps:

1. Run Canny Edge on the main image. [canny edge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXVlP.png)
2. Remove the background noise(of the canny edge image) using the image segmentation mask(I got from the ml-model). Here I use bitwise-and of the canny edge image and segmentation mask. [background noise removed canny edge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE53W.png)
3. In the 2nd step, some of the real edges of the person also get removed, and to restore those, I have used the breadth-first-search algorithm and run it up to some limit(suppose, up to 10 neighbors). [after BFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyjVj.png)
4. I shrink the segmentation mask and using this, removed the interior noise of the canny edge image. [removing the inside noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsNd5.png)

Now if I could somehow connect the edge line of the canny edge image, we would get a perfect segmentation. But I failed to do so.

Any suggestion will be helpful for me.